# Display images in a div instead of document top with JS

Tags: javascript, html, image

i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total_images = 4;
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
var random_img = new Array();

random_img[0] = '<a href="page1.html"><img src="img/logo (0).jpg"></a>';
random_img[1] = '<a href="page2.html"><img src="img/logo (1).jpg"></a>';
random_img[2] = '<a href="page3.html"><img src="img/logo (2).jpg"></a>';
random_img[3] = '<a href="page1.html"><img src="img/logo (3).jpg"></a>';

document.write(random_img[random_number]);
```

This code taks some photos from a folder and display them on the document top. I have 2 questions:

1. How can i make the scrip to display the images in the div with the ID boom1?
2. How can i chose a custom size for each image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using document.write as you have no control over the output. try something like:

```
var total_images = 4;
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
var random_img = [];
var target = document.getElementById('boom1');

random_img.push('<a href="page1.html"><img src="img/logo (0).jpg"></a>');
random_img.push('<a href="page2.html"><img src="img/logo (1).jpg"></a>');
random_img.push('<a href="page3.html"><img src="img/logo (2).jpg"></a>');
random_img.push('<a href="page1.html"><img src="img/logo (3).jpg"></a>');
// sizes can be set by adding width="" height="" in the img tag


target.innerHTML = random_img[random_number];
```

Make sure the code is run after the `boom1` element has been rendered in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

```js
var random_img = new Array();

random_img[0] = '<a href="page1.html"><img src="img/logo (0).jpg"></a>';

random_img[1] = '<a href="page2.html"><img src="img/logo (1).jpg"></a>';

random_img[2] = '<a href="page3.html"><img src="img/logo (2).jpg"></a>';

random_img[3] = '<a href="page1.html"><img src="img/logo (3).jpg"></a>';

for(var count=0; count < random_img.length; count++){
    $("#divID").append(random_img[count]);
    $("#divID").append('<br/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Main"> </div>
```

var random_img = new Array();

random_img[0] = '';

random_img[1] = '';

random_img[2] = '';

random_img[3] = '';

for(var count=0; count < random_img.length; count++)

{

```
$("#divID").append(random_img[count]);
$("#divID").append('<br/>');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Size**

```
<img src="blah blah" height="30px" width="30px">
```

**Custom write**

HTML

```
<div id="hi"></div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML = "<p>hi</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways. Append a Image-Element to the Div or set the image as background-image.

First:

```
var div = document.getElementById('boom1');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<img src="...." width="...." height="...." >';
```

Second:

```
var div = document.getElementById('boom1');
div.style.backgroundImage = "url('....')";
div.style.backgroundSize = "100px 100px";
```